# How to remove 'Main Menu' from my mobile view (using Superfish)?

Tags: navigation

I am using [Bootstrap Business](https://www.drupal.org/project/bootstrap_business) theme and I put [Superfish](https://www.drupal.org/project/superfish) module in my theme.

The problem is when it appears in Mobile View the title of *"Main Menu"* appear.

I would like to remove that title. However, I don't know how to make that.When click on the menu, it also involve that title.

[image]

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Go to **admin/structure/block** and look for **Main Menu** (should be in the Superfish region).

Click **configure** and set the title to not display. As the instructions for the **Block title** field say:

> Override the default title for the block. Use `<none>` to display no title, or leave blank to use the default block title. This field supports tokens.

Comment: I already tried for that but it still shows the "Menu" title. I think it is not associate with drupal block. It deals with superfish module.

Comment: I don't think so. Superfish doesn't provide a title. The title comes from your menu block. You have to actually enter <none> ... not just leave it blank. See `admin/help/menu_block`.

Answer (score 1):

I also tried configuring the block title to `<none>` but it didn't work.

Instead, the title comes from the menu settings. Go to **admin/structure/menu** (D7) and **edit menu** and change **Title**.

You can't leave it blank so you may be able to enter some whitespace characters. For me, I instead edited the title to just "Menu".